# jQuery Cycle Plugin is showing border of auto-generated links

Tags: jquery, css, cycle-plugin

[Here is my page](http://royalsofts.moon.pk/services.php), if you click business solutions, i.t consultancy, website development or design&print.. it displays the selection border, which is standard behavior, i have turned the border 0 with CSS but that is not workin... how to avoid it, i always hide this by matching the color of the background with the border or with the button itself but as you can see that it is not possible here.

WHAT TO DO...

the links are being generated by jQuery Cycle Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this snippet of code from a similar question.

:focus { outline: none; }

and make sure that is underneath the other CSS styling for the element, I believe focus is meant to be listed last.